# create react app - npm run build issues

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, create-react-app

I am using `create-react-app` to build an application and when I run npm run build it creates a build folder with static folder inside it which is expected.

`build`--> `static`

But when I see the index.html file inside the build folder, the path to assets is `/static` and not `/build/static` which is why the page does not load properly as it is missing the assets .

Is there any config setting I can do to fix this problem ?

Comment: If `index.html` is inside `build`, then `/static` would be the correct relative path for the assets, wouldn't it? I don't think this is the cause of your issue. Are you getting errors in your browser console when you try to load the page? If so, please edit them into your question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If all you want is to run your app, all that you have to do is run the command: `npm start`

But, if you are really trying to prefix the static references to upload your code on an specific subdirectory you should add on your `package.json` the homepage you want to use on your create-react-app.

So, if you want your react app to use `/build` in the beginning of each reference you should add the following line to your `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "/build",  
  ...
}
```

The following message is displayed when you generate your build without the homepage in the configurations:

````
The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root.
To override this, specify the homepage in your package.json.
For example, add this to build it for GitHub Pages:

  "homepage" : "http://myname.github.io/myapp",

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  yarn global add serve
  serve -s build```
````

Comment: this is creating issue in localhost. after add homepage when i run localhost it's also showing localhost:3000/build during start the system

Answer (score 3):

> But when I see the index.html file inside the build folder, the path to assets is `/static` and not `/build/static`

This behaviour is expected.

You're supposed to deploy the `build` folder and **serve the application from it**. Since `index.html` is inside `build`, it would be served for `/`, and files in `build/static/*` will be served for `/static/*`.

For more specific instructions for this, please read the [Deployment section](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment) of the User Guide.

Comment: Hey, @Dan Deployment section link is broken.

Comment: @Dan, "You're supposed to deploy the build folder and serve the application from it." Where can I find more information on this topic particularly?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to use unimported assets.

I prefer to create an assets folder and place these sort of files here, and then import/use them accordingly.

From [the documentation](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-images-fonts-and-files):

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.png'; // Tell Webpack this JS file uses this image

console.log(logo); // /logo.84287d09.png

function Header() {
  // Import result is the URL of your image
  return <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />;
}

export default Header;
```

If you really want to use the `public` folder, you can [use the `PUBLIC_URL` variable.](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#using-the-public-folder)

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
```